# Does rabies have an almost 100% mortality rate with around 160 deaths per day?

Tags: medical-science, mortality

One of my favourite information snippets to dish out to unsuspecting friends is that there are roughly only 10 recorded cases of rabies survival without vaccination, while it's estimated that around 160 people die from the virus every day. This also means more people die every couple of hours than there are known non-vaccination survivors (take that, anti-vacciners!). Coupled with it being a very nasty way to die, this factoid acts as a pretty effective conversation killer (yes, I sometimes *can* be that guy).

Anyway, I soon realised that the data I was dishing out (10 survivors, 160 deaths a day) had simply been heard from random sources, and I had no idea if they were actually founded or not.

So my question is: Does rabies in fact kill practically 100% of people who contract it, with around 100 deaths per day and only a single- or double-digit number of people having survived it **after symptoms developed**?

Claim: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gf2bObJGFkg

EDIT: It would also be interesting to learn what percentage of people who are vaccinated still die from rabies.

Comment: Look on wikipedia, the entry on rabies has all the information you are looking for, and probably enough references. Your numbers are basically confirmed there, although the death number is a little smaller. Interesting to note is that according to Wikipedia, the normal treatment would be to vaccinate short after the infection (survival rate seems to be good with that treatment if done shortly after the infection), and the only succesful treatment without vaccination has a survival rate of 8-12%. All this please with a grain of salt, this comment is just the digest of a quick read on Wikipedia

Comment: The survival rate of 8-12% doesn't seem to add up. On a list of disease fatality rates wiki says that Rabies has a untreated rate of "~100%"

Comment: "the CFR is near 100%" http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_human_disease_case_fatality_rates

Comment: I cite Wikipedia: 5 of the first 43 patients (12%) treated with the Milwaukee protocol survived, and those receiving treatment survived longer than those not receiving the treatment.

Comment: Interesting, this would definitely suggest that there are many more survivors than just ten, if out of 43 there are already 5 survivors. I guess the majority of cases occur in LEDCs so most patients don't/can't receive proper care and so are substantially more likely to die.

Comment: Read the Wikipedia page, please, and don't discuss with me through comments about things we both don't know about. The treatment I cite has only been applied to a few people and is fairly new, and difficult to pull off. (Apparently) I understand the "of the first 43" to mean that there were only 43 up to now. Note that Wikipedia says in the US there are only like 2 or three deaths per year, most are in Asia and Africa.

Comment: http://www.mysanantonio.com/news/local_news/article/First-unvaccinated-rabies-survivor-shares-story-3653582.php this girl is the apperently the first documented case of survival, only 8 years ago...

Comment: Unfortunately local news isn't exactly the most reliable source :P and _of course_ they don't validate their claim.

Comment: @Noodlemanny actually this girls story is all over the internet, her treatment was the first example of the milwaukee protocol. so yes its fact. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Milwaukee_protocol

Comment: @Himarm I wasn't refuting it as fact merely saying that the article isn't a reliable source.

Comment: @Noodlemanny actually i linked the wrong article lol, i had one with sources that linked me to this local one and i mis linked mah bad for coming off rude.

Comment: In order for your factoid to be relevant, you need to include what percentage of vaccinated people who contract rabies die.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

[According to the website of the journal Nature](http://www.nature.com/scitable/blog/viruses101/is_rabies_really_100_fatal):

> Jeanna Geise was only 15 years old when she became the world's first known survivor of Rabies without receiving any vaccination. Her miraculous survival has not only challenged a time-honored scientific fact, but has also brought about a new method of Rabies treatment, known as the Milwaukee Protocol. It had long been thought that Rabies is 100% fatal in humans who are not vaccinated. However, to the surprise of the medical world, Jeanna showed that fatal the virus can be beaten sans vaccination.

So prior to 2004, the disease was 100% fatal without receiving a vaccination.

However, "receiving a vaccination" includes receiving a vaccination after being bitten by the rabid animal.

For a recent (April 2015) update see [Temporal evolution on MRI of successful treatment of rabies](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0899707115001059) which explains 3 people have now survived, having received the Milwaukee protocol, while 26 have died despite such treatment.  So still very fatal, but not 100% fatal.

As far as deaths, an [NIH presentation](https://www.niaid.nih.gov/news/events/meetings/Viral%20Infections/Documents/wilde.pdf) states over 55,000 deaths per year world wide, specifically including:

India 19,200
China 2,217
Rest of Asia 9,328
Africa  23,979

Comment: I think you should perhaps stress that we're actually talking about treatment protocols, not "vaccination" (i.e. disease prevention). In other words, the OP's use of this factoid is misleading.

Comment: and that the vaccine must be given before signs of rabies starts, once the signs starts the vaccine becomes worthless. its an important distinction since, after rabies symptoms appears is when it was fatal not before, so after the symptoms appeared these 3 have survived.

Comment: Agree with fredsbend. While technically the treatment *is* a vaccination, most people tend to think of a vaccination as something given before you are exposed to the disease. in this case it is usually given after exposure to the disease, and is therefore also a *treatment*.

Comment: @DJClayworth technically its still a vaccine as its working to prevent the infection, a rabies bite takes about a week before you actually are "infected" and incurable. your body has a week with the vaccine to build up anti bodies it needs to fight the real infection that starts after a week. rabies essentially lies dormant for the first week after the bite.

Comment: @Himarm Yes, that's exactly what I meant.

Comment: @DJClayworth: There are many people who get the vaccination before being exposed.  My wife is a vet student, and she *(and all the other students)* are required to be updated on their rabies vaccinations, and are required to keep it updated when they begin practicing.  I'd bet other professions (eg. vet-techs, dog-catchers, etc) have similar requirements.  Plus there are people who are exposed more than once, but don't need to get the vaccination a second time.

Comment: @BlueRaja-DannyPflughoeft Yes, many people get it before exposure, but most people don't.

Comment: i think the OP's factoid is not misleading, because the vaccine is still a vaccine and anti-vacciners would still be against it(however if in anti-vacciners gets bitten who knows if they'll stand their ground or not), aka its not a treatment, its still a preventative measure so fredsbends statement is incorrect.

Comment: @fredsbend being bitten by a rabid animal is very treatable by vaccination after being bitten, but does one "have rabies" at the that point?

Comment: @Himarm Anti-vaccers are typically against prevention vaccination, not treatment after infection, administered wholesale to the population without regard for actual need, patient wishes, and possible adverse reaction, and for illnesses that are not necessarily deadly or even permanently debilitating. The Rabies disease, vaccine, and conventional practice for treatment and prevention is very must *not* against most anti-vaccer preferences. In that respect, the OP's use of the factoid is at least misused and possibly misleading. But since this site is about fact proofing, we should stop here.

Comment: @DavePhD Depends on your definition of infection. All of them include that an invasive, live micro-organism must be present within the body. Some also include that the micro-organism must be actively reproducing. I don't know specifically about Rabies, but I don't consider "active reproduction" to really matter if it is eminent without treatment. Also "have rabies" may mean "presents symptoms" or "is positive for live virus in lab testing".

Comment: @fredsbend but if the "micro organism is present" definition is used, then even without any type of treatment (including vaccination), the 100% fatal statistic isn't true.  Only when a narrower definition of having rabies is used, it is 100% fatal without treatment.

Comment: @DavePhD I've always heard that "Rabies is nearly 100% treatable, **but without treatment is nearly 100% fatal.**" I think that's much more descriptive than the OP's poor use of factoids. For example, anti-vaccers oppose MMR, DTAP, etc. Vaccines that are given wholesale to the population. Rabies vaccine is not even close to that. It's given when it's actually needed. The OP doesn't clarify any of that with his factoids, making the "argument" look foolish.

Comment: @fredsbend The thing is, if an unvaccinated person is bit in head by a rabid dog, they have a 45% of getting the disease, and in the leg only a 5% chance. Even if the micro organism is present, they don't necessarily get the disease.  http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC2626230/ There is a distinction between being bit by a rabid animal and a person having rabies, and if the person actually has rabies the vaccine is not a successful treatment.

Comment: @fredsbend: According to the stats, rabies is 10% treatable - that is, without vaccination prior to exposure (as opposed to vaccine treatment after exposure) rabies is 90% fatal (based form the fact that 26 out of the 29 people who'be been given the Milwaukee protocol died - only 3 survived)

Comment: sounds like you'd rather contract and not treat ebola than rabies!

Comment: [Radiolab has an episode about Jeanna's case](http://www.radiolab.org/story/312245-rodney-versus-death/). They interview her and Dr. Rodney Willoughby who came up with the Milwaukee Protocol out of desperation. They discuss why early treatment is so important and effective (rabies literally crawls up your nerves to the brain) and why it becomes untreatable once it reaches the brain. That link also contains several other sources.

Comment: @DavePhD in the 95% of cases that a person gets bitten in the leg and survives, do the victims test positive for rabies antibodies? Did the body fight off the infection, or does the infection not take hold? You gloss over this, but this is crucial to a correct answer. If the body can fight off the virus, then the virus is not 100% fatal.

Comment: @AleksandrDubinsky "During the incubation period, rabies virus is evidently segregated from the immune system, since no antibody responses are seen. Only after neurological symptoms develop do antibodies appear in the serum and later in the CSF. Demonstration of antibodies is thus useful diagnostically only in late phases of the disease."  http://cid.oxfordjournals.org/content/30/1/4.full So, no, you wouldn't detect antibodies for most of the people bite in the leg.

Answer (score 11):

This is [one of a number of sites about rabies treatment](http://www.nhs.uk/Conditions/Rabies/Pages/Treatment.aspx). The page explains the perhaps surprising statistics.

- If you have been exposed to rabies, for example bitten by a rabid
  animal, but have not developed rabies symptoms, the the usual
  treatment is a rabies vaccine course and/or rabies immunoglobin.
  Rabies treatments when you have not developed symptoms are very successful.
- If you have symptoms of rabies, treatment usually focuses on making you as comfortable as possible. This is because rabies is almost always fatal when it reaches this stage. There is an experimental treatment called the Milwaulkee Protocol, but it has been effective in only three cases where symptoms have developed.

This explains the situation. Your 100% fatality quote is accurate, provided you are talking about only people who have symptoms. **Rabies is indeed almost always fatal once it reaches the symptoms stage. Only 3 people are known to have survived after symptoms. With prompt treatment (i.e. vaccination) as soon as exposure is suspected it is highly curable.**

People are sometimes confused because the rabies vaccine is most given as a treatment, i.e. after exposure, and not before exposure like most vaccines.

According to [Scientific American](http://www.scientificamerican.com/article/jeanna-giese-rabies-survivor/):

> Rabies is 100 percent preventable with vaccinations if patients receive them before the onset of symptoms

Comment: No answer on the exact number of survivors though? The Milwaukee Protocol seems to be the thing saving people.

Comment: @Noodlemanny it only saved 3 people as of April 2015

Comment: @Noodlemanny No, the thing saving people is getting rabies vaccination treatment after exposure - i.e. after the animal bite - but before symptoms have developed.

Comment: True but the Milwaukee Protocol seems to create _tiny_ a possibility of survival after symptoms develop. However there seems to be some disagreement over whether it was the technique that saved patients or inherent immune resistance.

Comment: The Milwaulkee Protocol has (maybe) moved the statistics from "100% fatal" to "almost 100% fatal", which is great for the people saved but not a big statistical impact.

Comment: Agreed. bottom line is if you ever get bitten by anything ever at all; get vaccinated for rabies. Hell, if you bite yourself it probably wouldn't hurt to vaccinate :P

Comment: i mean 3 out of 100s of thousands of deaths, wouldnt you still be able to say that its 100% fatal, because in reality even with these 3 survivors its still like 99.999999999999% (repeating of course) chance you'll die.

Answer (score 5):

Googleing "Rabies kills 160 people daily" returns multiple results that seem to reference the same study. However good old BBC actually linked to it thankfully.

> loss of human lives (approximately 59,000 annually)

(April 16 2015, Estimating the Global Burden of Endemic Canine Rabies, multiple authors) http://journals.plos.org/plosntds/article?id=10.1371/journal.pntd.0003709

Regarding the number of actual survivors Reading through the Milwaukee Protocol article on Wikipedia produced this result:

> Some critics say those survivors (5 out of 36 survival rate)...
>   despite no documented survivors before them

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Milwaukee_protocol#Survival_hypotheses This seems to suggest that there are 5 known survivors but it's only implied and doesn't have proper citation.

Look at DavePhD's and DJClayworth's answers for information about fatality rates.